# Count number of values in an object

Tags: java

I have written code like this:

```
public void SetPosition(int lfp, int lhp, int rfp, int rhp)
{
        leftFront = lfp;
        leftHind = lhp;
        rightFront = rfp;
        rightHind = rhp;

        System.out.print((lfp+1) + "...");
        System.out.print((lhp+1) + "...");
        System.out.print((rfp+1) + "...");
        System.out.println((rhp+1) + "...");

}
```

Now I want to count how many (lfp+1)s are in my output... Please let me know how to do this...

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. You have an integer `lfp` with a value that you're printing. What do you want to actually count?

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Is this *all* of the output? If so, then it's just the number of lines divided by four... But I suspect that's not what you're after. Please give more information.

Comment: Do you want to add a counter to say how many output lines you have printed?

Comment: @Life4menu This question has been outstanding for 17 days with no additional comments. If something is confusing for you, it is probably confusing for others. Please take the time to clarify your question, and even post your own answer if you have solved it on your own. Even if it was a simple misunderstanding, it will likely help someone to just say what you didn't get at first. Everyone is welcome here, but it seems to me to be pretty unfair to ask a question and then in turn ignore the responses of people who spend time trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a static counter

```
private static counter = 0 ;
```

increment this in the function after checking the values of lfp